# Why is my XML file on Android being cut off at 1000 Bytes

Tags: android, xml, filewriter

I am trying to write an Android application that can write data to an XML file stored on the sd card. All seems to work well, but my XML file gets cut off at exactly 1000 bytes. Here is the code:

```
package brochard.chad.fieldReport;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter; 

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;

public class XMLWriter implements Serializable {

private String filename;
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
private StringWriter output = new StringWriter(100);
FieldReportDBAdapter dbA;
static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

public XMLWriter (String _filename){
    filename = _filename;
}

public boolean beginXMlreport(Cursor cursor) {
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(output);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", false);
        serializer.setPrefix("w", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml");
        serializer.startTag("w", "wordDocument");
        serializer.startTag("w", "styles");
        serializer.startTag("w", "style");
        serializer.attribute("w", "type", "paragraph");
        serializer.attribute("w", "styeId", "ReportHeading");
        serializer.startTag("w", "name");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "Heading");
        serializer.endTag("w", "name");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "center");
        serializer.endTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "b");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "on");
        serializer.endTag("w", "b");
        serializer.startTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "48");
        serializer.endTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.endTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.endTag("w", "style");
        serializer.startTag("w", "style");
        serializer.attribute("w", "type", "paragraph");
        serializer.attribute("w", "styleId", "SubHeading");
        serializer.startTag("w", "name");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "SubHeading");
        serializer.endTag("w", "name");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "left");
        serializer.endTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "b");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "on");
        serializer.endTag("w", "b");
        serializer.startTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "36");
        serializer.endTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.endTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.endTag("w", "style");
        serializer.startTag("w", "style");
        serializer.attribute("w", "type", "paragraph");
        serializer.attribute("w", "styleId", "Text");
        serializer.startTag("w", "name");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "Text");
        serializer.endTag("w", "name");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "left");
        serializer.endTag("w", "jc");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "b");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "off");
        serializer.endTag("w", "b");
        serializer.startTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "24");
        serializer.endTag("w", "sz");
        serializer.endTag("w", "rPr");
        serializer.endTag("w", "style");
        serializer.endTag("w", "styles");   
        serializer.startTag("w", "body");
        serializer.startTag("w", "p");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "ReportHeading");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "r");
        serializer.startTag("w", "t");
        serializer.text("Field Report");
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "t");
        serializer.endTag("w", "r");
        serializer.endTag("w", "p");
        serializer.startTag("w", "p");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "SubHeading");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "r");
        serializer.startTag("w", "t");
        serializer.text("Project Title");
        serializer.endTag("w", "t");
        serializer.endTag("w", "r");
        serializer.endTag("w", "p");
        serializer.startTag("w", "p");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.attribute("w", "val", "Text");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pStyle");
        serializer.endTag("w", "pPr");
        serializer.startTag("w", "r");
        serializer.startTag("w", "t");
        serializer.text("Owner: "+
        cursor.getString(FieldReportDBAdapter.OWNER_COLUMN));
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.text("High Temp: "+
                cursor.getString(FieldReportDBAdapter.HIGHTEMP_COLUMN));
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.text("Low Temp: "+
                cursor.getString(FieldReportDBAdapter.LOWTEMP_COLUMN));
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.text("Conditions: "+
                cursor.getString(FieldReportDBAdapter.CONDITIONS_COLUMN));
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.text("Notes: "+
                cursor.getString(FieldReportDBAdapter.NOTES_COLUMN));
        serializer.startTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "br");
        serializer.endTag("w", "t");
        serializer.endTag("w", "r");
        serializer.endTag("w", "p");
        serializer.endTag("w", "body");
        serializer.endTag("w", "wordDocument");   
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}


    public boolean WriteToFile() {
        FileWriter fWriter;
        try{
             fWriter = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                     "/"+filename);
             Log.v("OUTPUT",output.toString());
             fWriter.write(output.toString());
             fWriter.flush();
             fWriter.close();
             return true;
         }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  return false;
         }
    }           
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated! The logcat shows the file just the way I want it, it just does not get to the file.

Comment: To confirm: You're saying the entire thing gets logged, but the XML file only contains the first 1,000 bytes. Is that correct?

Comment: When u say 1000 bytes, do you mean that the output object is getting cut at 1000bytes or u can see only 1000 bytes in the logcat?

Comment: The file that is created is exactly 1000 bytes. It truncates the rest of the string. In the logcat the entire string is there.

Comment: No scratch that last comment. I checked again, the String is cut off in the logcat as well. So this means it is getting shortened before writing to the file. I tried increasing the size of the stringwriter's buffer, since the doc says it defaults to 16 chars.That had no effect, Is there a similar. Buffer for the Xmlserializer?

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem now. Thank you for your comments, they led me to the reference on XMLSerilizer. Once I read through the doc I realized I forgot to call endDocument() on the XML serializer. Once I added a call to this method, the code is performing as expected.

Comment: Could you please accept this answer? I found this very useful.